# semi surpvised learning with CNN for image classification

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have the following folders labeled folder cat & dog and one folder of images without a label

- I want to perform semi surpvised learning with CNN train , test and evaluate my model
  So far I know how to train my model on with_label data (I trained the model on all the labeled images)
- I'm not sure what to do next  and when I can split my data for test, train and validation should I split the data first then perform datagen or should I split later after training the model on the images with label

```
My Data
|
|__ with_label 
|   |
|   |__ cat_images (50 images)
|   |
|   |__ lion_images (100 images)
|
|__ without_label (1000 images)
```

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
with_label_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/with_label',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary'
)
x_with, y_with = labeled_data_gen.next()

without_label_data_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/without_label ',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False
)
x_without = unlabeled_data_gen.next()[0]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

Train the model on the labeled data
model.fit(x_labeled, y_labeled, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @pavel I want to apply semi surpvised learning which is a mix of supervised and unsupervised learning (using bother labeled and unlabeled data) I run my model on the label data but I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: You might want to look into [pytorch-metric-learning](https://kevinmusgrave.github.io/pytorch-metric-learning/losses/), and contrastive learning. Usually train unlabelled data as contrastive loss (same class = augmented input samples - different sample = different class), and contrastive + classification loss for labelled data

Comment: You can start with [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.12848) ([official repo](https://github.com/google-research/uda)), and followinf Google's scholar citations [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=12880251999793471515)